# passar uma variável do Java script pra o php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá  tenho um cod em js que  pega  id de uma campo  e com este id(valor) preciso usar em if else dentro php para exibir posts relacionados aquele id  conforme o click do usuário
a baixo o cod que pega  o id

```
 <script>  
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $(".linha-produtos").click(function(){
                var categorias = $(this).attr("id");
                //console.log(categorias);
                $("#recebe-indice").attr('src',categorias);       
           });
           //aqui
          $(".nav-item").click(function(){ 
           
            var capacitancia = $(this).attr("id");
           
                        
       });
      });
   
    </script>
```

***Meu código PHP***

```
<?php
    
    $nome = $_POST['capacitanciaa'];

   if ( $categories1->have_posts()  ) : while ( $categories1->have_posts()  ) : $categories1->the_post();
       
         $linha = get_the_title() ; 
         $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ); ;
        
        
        if($category->name ==  "440V")
         echo'<p id ="capacitancias" class="tabela-linhax"> '.$linha.' </p>';  else{

    };?>                           
        
                        

       
<?php   
        endwhile; 
        endif;   
?>
```

Comment: sua pergunta está bem confusa. Mas com as informações que estão nela não da para faze o que você quer, o AJAX foi feito para fazer requisições assincronas. Para fazer isso que você quer se eu entendi bem, você vai usar a requisição AJAX para um arquivo `.php` que retorne um `json` para você no HTML através do AJAX/Javascript conseguir mostrar em tela de acordo com o "Id" do botão que você clica.

Comment: oie , depois de montar o ajax    var capacitancia =  jQuery(this).attr("id");
        //console.log(capacitancia);
        var page ="https://williarts.ga/tslcomponetes/produtos/"
        var data  = capacitancia;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    url:data,
});

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score -1):

O JavaScript é uma linguagem que neste caso é executada no front end ou na máquina do usuário, já o PHP é uma linguagem de back end e será executada no lado do servidor.

Desta forma você precisa controlar o comportamento do usuário via JavaScript e para passar o valor da variável para o PHP você precisa executar um AJAX, algo do tipo:

```
 $(".linha-produtos").click(function(){
            var categorias = $(this).attr("id");
            //console.log(categorias);
            $.ajax( "example.php" )
            .done(function() {
              //Quando terminar de fazer a requisição e tiver uma resposta do php positiva
             })
             .fail(function() {
                //Quando a requisição falhar por algum erro
              })    
       });
```

Assim você controla na tela do usuário envia e comunica com o PHP e pega o retorno e trata as ações na tela do usuário sem ter que recarregar a página.

Comment: oie andre  primeiramente obrigado pela atenção ,  pois entao eu estou chamando em um ajax , so que minha duvida  e  como o meu php vai receber  a variável pois  quero usar para comparação em um if

Comment: $(".nav-item").click(function(){ 
     
    var capacitancia =  jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var url_atual = window.location.href;
    console.log(capacitancia );
     var page ="https://williarts.ga/tslcomponetes/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/shortcodes/produtos-shortcode.php/";
    $.ajax({
        
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    url: page,
    data: {'escolha' :capacitancia },
   
   
   
});

Comment: Olá Fabio se você fizer o seu ajax com o méthodo Get você pode usar do lado do php (puro) $_GET['a_Variavel'] se for post $_POST['a_variavel'], se você estiver usando algum framework (o que sugiro como uma boa pratica) aí precisaria verificar na documentação do framework por que cada um pode tratar de formas diferentes.